# How to convert pandas PeriodIndex into a specific financial year string format?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm looking to use a periodIndex series and to create a new series that displays the current financial year in this format 'yyyy/yy'. For example using the UK financial year as an example - > 01/04 to 31/03.

```
 df  = pd.DataFrame({ 
         'dates' : pd.date_range('3/01/11', periods= 3, freq='M'),
         'amounts': np.random.randint(10, 100_000, 3)
 })

 df

      dates     amounts     
0   2011-03-31  28618   
1   2011-04-30  517     
2   2011-05-31  69892
```

My desired outcome is presented by series `fy` below. I've used `pd.PeriodIndex(df['dates'], freq = 'Q-MAR').strftime('%y')`. So far unable to achieve the below outcome.

```
      dates     amounts     fy
0   2011-03-31  28618   2010/11
1   2011-04-30  517     2011/12
2   2011-05-31  69892   2011/12
```

Thank you in advance.

numpy 1.15.4

pandas 0.23.4

python 3.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({ 
         'dates' : pd.date_range('3/01/11', periods= 20, freq='2M'),
         'amounts': np.random.randint(10, 100_000, 20)
 })


p = pd.PeriodIndex(df['dates'], freq = 'Q-MAR')
df['fy'] = [(a - b).strftime('%Y/')+(a - b + 4).strftime('%y') for a, b in zip(p, p.quarter)]
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['fy1'] = [f'{x}/{str(x + 1)[2:]}' for x in (df.dates - pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()).dt.year]

print (df)

        dates  amounts       fy
0  2011-03-31    30629  2010/11
1  2011-05-31    66159  2011/12
2  2011-07-31    48821  2011/12
3  2011-09-30    92771  2011/12
4  2011-11-30    55348  2011/12
5  2012-01-31    10745  2011/12
6  2012-03-31    91046  2011/12
7  2012-05-31    32632  2012/13
8  2012-07-31    77657  2012/13
9  2012-09-30    95364  2012/13
10 2012-11-30    78078  2012/13
11 2013-01-31    44535  2012/13
12 2013-03-31    89158  2012/13
13 2013-05-31    94263  2013/14
14 2013-07-31    99759  2013/14
15 2013-09-30    59057  2013/14
16 2013-11-30    38363  2013/14
17 2014-01-31    98069  2013/14
18 2014-03-31    44797  2013/14
19 2014-05-31    87895  2014/15
```

Comment: thanks for the above. I dont belive the above code line will produce the outcome.  The three values `fy` retreived will default to the same year presented in `dates` ignoring the `PeriodIndex()`. i.e. `['2011/11', '2011/11',  '2011/11']`

Comment: sorry forgot to tag your username

Comment: @Francisco - working on it... One thing - `2011-03-31` is not `2011/12` ?

Comment: thank you. For the case  2011- 03- 31 is the last day of the financial year  2010/11. 2011-04-01 will be the first day for fy 2011/12.  I've notice the PeriodIndex always will dsplay the later year correctly in the desired notation. ie 2011-04-01 will be `2012Q1` and 2011-03-31 `2011Q4` .

Comment: perfect. Thank you for this and all your SO answers! Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for financial year

```
pd.PeriodIndex(df['dates'], freq = 'Q-MAR').strftime('%F')
```

Reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.strftime.html